# Fetch data from database using procedure

Tags: java, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to read data from oracle database by calling procedure from java code.
If I am running the procedure from sqldeveloper, I can see that the procedure is giving me the correct output.But when I try to run using java program,I am getting error.

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY VISIONEMPLOYEES AS
     PROCEDURE Employees(
        p_id IN NUMBER,
        p_ref_cursor OUT sys_refcursor )
        AS
        BEGIN

       OPEN p_ref_cursor FOR
       SELECT id, name, age FROM emp WHERE id = p_id;

        EXCEPTION
         WHEN OTHERS THEN
          ROLLBACK;
          RAISE;
      END Employees;
    END VISIONEMPLOYEES;
```

Java Code:

```
public static void callOracleStoredProcOUTParameter()
  {
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    CallableStatement cb = null;
    String qry = "{VISIONEMPLOYEES.Employees(?,?)}";
    try {

                         conn = getDbConnection();  
                         cb = conn.prepareCall(qry);
                         cb.setInt(1, 1);
                         cb.registerOutParameter(2, OracleTypes.CURSOR);
                         cb.executeUpdate();
                        String userName = cb.getString(2);
                        System.out.println("UserName is : " + userName);

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            System.out.println(e);
                        }
                    }
```

java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Please tell me what is wrong with the above written code.

Comment: Show us the code you use to run the procedure and the errors your are getting when the code is run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're missing the `call` keyword in your `qry` String.

```
String qry = "{call VISIONEMPLOYEES.Employees(?,?)}";
```

(see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/CallableStatement.html)